# Copy a string from a pointer to an index within an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

As stated in the title, I wanted to copy a string from a `char` pointer to location within an array of `char` pointers. When doing `strcpy()`, the output results in seg fault, but don't understand why this occurs.

The abbreviated code has the following:

```
void make_history(char *entry) {
    //static char past_entries[10][10];
    static char *past_entries[10];
    static int index = 0;
    static int array_index = 0;

    char *input;
    if((input = strchr(entry, '\n')) != NULL)
        *input = '\0';

    if(strcmp(entry, "history") != 0) {
        strcpy(past_entries[index], entry);
        *past_entries[index] = &entry;
        index = (index + 1) % 10;
        array_index++;
    }
}
```

Instead of trying to return a 2d array (which is also very tricky), I thought it would be easier to copy the date from `entry` to the location within the array of pointers `past_entries`. Again, `strcpy` does not work, is there a valid reason as to why this occurs, and a possible workaround or solution to this fix?

Thank you

Comment: Please show how you call `make_history`. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: I mean, the call to the function is just `make_history("message")` where "message is the string which I want to add to the array. There is not much to it.

Comment: You should mention this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `past_entries` is just an array of pointers, but you don't allocate any memory to them (initially pointing to `NULL`). You then try to write to those locations, hence the crash.

To solve this, just allocate some memory before you try to copy your string to it:

```
past_entries[index] = malloc(strlen(entry) + 1);
```

Of course you should not forget to free all of this in the end.

Oh and, remove that line: `*past_entries[index] = &entry;`. It tries to assign *a pointer to a character array* to *a character*.

Comment: Since `past_entries` is declared `static`, it is in fact guaranteed the elements will initially be null pointers. Still bad news.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you, I've fixed that part of the answer.

Comment: @Qubit I wanted to have the values be static as I want the array to update for each call to the function. The general idea is to create a circular array that shows that last 10 entries made -- kind of a like a history

Comment: I think you misunderstand what this does. Sure, you can have a static array of 10 character pointers and the addresses will be saved between function calls. But you still need them to point somewhere meaningful for them to store data (your entries). You can either do that with the line you have commented out (if you know an upper bound to the size of the entries) or dynamically using malloc (if you do not know an upper bound).

Comment: @Qubit I guess I just am having trouble understanding how this new pointer is returned

Comment: All this line does is allocates some memory and stores the location in `past_entries[index]`, which is a pointer type. That way `past_entries[index]` actually points to memory that belongs to you so that you can read/write to it. I don't understand what you mean by *is returned*, we're not returning anything in this function.